# How to always move down a cell column by 1 in excel?

Tags: python, excel

I would like to know if there is a way of moving down a cell column by 1 when I have inserted value in a cell. For example, I created a loop program where if I pressed the key "q", the program will get the current date and time value and print out to excel sheet to a specific cell('A1'). However, if I pressed the key "q" again, the program will print out the value to cell('A1') instead of moving down to cell('A2').

Is there any way I can always print out value to the next column like a loop increment?

Here is the program that I have:

```
import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook

current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
current_datetime.strftime('%x %X')

datetime = 'A1'     #cell coordinate

book = load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')    

sheet = book['Data']                  

sheet[datetime] = current_datetime

book.save('Sample.xlsx')
```

The software that I used is Python 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like you need a counter of sorts, that will determine where to input the new date based on the data already saved in your workbook.

Your cell coordinate should then be given by:

datetime = 'A' + str(i+1)

where 'i' is a counter indicating how many cells have already been filled. For example, if all cells in a row are empty, your i = 0 and datetime will be equal to 'A' + str(1) => 'A1', which is the static value you currently get. As the counter goes up, the cell for storing the new value gets shifted rightwards (that is, columnwise).

There are plenty of ways to make a counter. You could store the counter in a spare cell on your Excel file. Alternative, you could iterate throught the columns until you find the first empty column (a while loop) and return its coordinate.

Comment: When I added datetime = 'A' + str(i+1) and i = 0, the cell coordination in excel is at 'A1'. So when I tried to change the value of i to 1, the cell coordination is at 'A2'. May I know if there is a way of always increase i by 1? I tried to use i = i +1 and i += 1 but somehow it didnt have any increment.